# set option value as array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, html-input

Setting up some permissions.  I'd like to be able to set my item.roles as an array.  Is this possible?  If not what's the smartest way to go about getting my item.roles model to be an array in the end?

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.roles" ng-init="item.roles[0]='client'">
    <option value="[super, admin, producer, resource, client]">Super</option>
    <option value="[admin, producer, resource, client]">Admin</option>
    <option value="[producer, resource, client]">Producer</option>
    <option value="[resource, client]">Resource</option>
    <option value="[client]">Client</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: You should probably define these array values within your controller.

Comment: You should create a map in controller with key being the role and value being an array with roles.

Comment: can you make an example? I'm new to map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngList](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList) directive:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-list ng-model="item.roles" ng-init="item.roles=['client']">
    <option value="super, admin, producer, resource, client">Super</option>
    <option value="admin, producer, resource, client">Admin</option>
    <option value="producer, resource, client">Producer</option>
    <option value="resource, client">Resource</option>
    <option value="client">Client</option>
</select>
```

Note, that option values in this case are comma separated list (or you can change delimiter).

`ngList` directive is used to convert delimited list of values to/from array:

> Text input that converts between a delimited string and an array of strings. The default delimiter is a comma followed by a space - equivalent to ng-list=", ". You can specify a custom delimiter as the value of the ngList attribute - for example, ng-list=" | ".

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TbkEne7ap4WpCS4UPj7U?p=preview